# How to access old value - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to store the previous value of myRover.position. I need to access it in order to backup when approaching an obstacle.

```
var myRover = {
position: [0, 0],
direction: 'N',
obstacleX: [0],
obstacleY: [2],
marsGrid: [
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
};

//prevent rover from falling off of planet Mars!
//my best attempt at wrapping a 2d array :-(
function preventSuddenDeath() {
if (myRover.position[0] > 9) {
myRover.position[0] = 0;
}
if (myRover.position[0] < 0) {
myRover.position[0] = 9;
}
if (myRover.position[1] > 9) {
myRover.position[1] = 0;
}
if (myRover.position[1] < 0) {
myRover.position[1] = 9;
}
}
```

This is my function for maneuvering the obstacle.

```
function maneuverObstacle() {
if (myRover.position[0] == myRover.obstacleX && myRover.position[1] ==    myRover.obstacleY) {
console.log("Crater ahead at " + myRover.position + ". Please change  direction!");
return myRover.position();
}
}
```

I've tried setting the oldValue equal to the currentValue as such and as I would assume, it just rewrites the oldValue to the current one.

```
function manueverObstacle() {
var oldPosition = myRover.position;
if (myRover.position[0] == myRover.obstacleX && myRover.position[1] ==   myRover.obstacleY) {
console.log("Display value of myRover.position: " + myRover.position);
console.log("Display value of oldPosition: " + oldPosition);
return myRover.position();
}
---->Rover is at 0,0 and heading N
//here I've given it the commands to turn right and go forward twice in order to test it
---->0,0
---->0,1
//breaks at 0,2 due to obstacle
----> Display value of myRover.position: 0,2
----> Display value of oldPosition: 0,2
```

And the rest if helpful.

```
function move_forward() {
if (myRover.direction == 'N') {
myRover.position[0] -= 1;
} else if (myRover.direction == 'E') {
myRover.position[1] += 1;
} else if (myRover.direction == 'S') {
myRover.position[0] += 1;
} else if (myRover.direction == 'W') {
myRover.position[1] -= 1;
} preventSuddenDeath();
}

function move_backward() {
if (myRover.direction == 'N') {
myRover.position[0] += 1;
} else if (myRover.direction == 'E') {
myRover.position[1] -= 1;
} else if (myRover.direction == 'S') {
myRover.position[0] -= 1;
} else if (myRover.direction == 'W') {
myRover.position[1] += 1;
} preventSuddenDeath();
}

function turn_left() {
if (myRover.direction == 'N') {
myRover.direction = 'W';
} else if (myRover.direction == 'E') {
myRover.direction = 'N';
} else if (myRover.direction == 'S') {
myRover.direction = 'E';
} else if (myRover.direction == 'W') {
myRover.direction = 'S';
}
}


function turn_right() {
if (myRover.direction == 'N') {
myRover.direction = 'E';
} else if (myRover.direction == 'E') {
myRover.direction = 'S';
} else if (myRover.direction == 'S') {
myRover.direction = 'W';
} else if (myRover.direction == 'W') {
myRover.direction = 'N';
}
}

function letsGoMrRover() {

//take user input from html prompt and convert the string to an array
var commandString = document.getElementById("command").value;
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var csLength = commandString.length;
var commandArray = [];

//console.log the starting position
output.innerHTML = "Rover is at " + myRover.position + " and heading " +   myRover.direction + "<br />";

for (var i=0; i < csLength; i++) {
commandArray[i] = commandString[i];

switch (commandArray[i]) {
  case 'f':
    move_forward();
    break;
  case 'b':
    move_backward();
    break;
  case 'l':
    turn_left();
    break;
  case 'r':
    turn_right();
    break;
  }
maneuverObstacle();
console.log(myRover.position);
}
}
```

Comment: Just make a variable named `prev` or something.

Comment: I would check for the obstacle before moving the rover. make checkObstacle a function that takes the robot x,y as parameters and returns if its okay to move, that way you can pass x+1,y before actually changing robot x to x+1

Comment: Why are the obstacle and the mars grid part of the rover object? These seem like three distinct things.

Comment: " it just rewrites the prevValue to the current one." What does this mean? Can you give a complete example that I can run myself?

Comment: I think that was just part of my original attempt at getting position[0,0] and marsGrid to "sync" so I just stuck with it. The assignment is due in a couple of days and although I now know of many better ways to write the code in that program, I'm worried changing one big thing is going to break many other things!

Comment: I don't know how to reduce that program enough to send you an example. I'm very new at this! I have been using CodePen however to test out my code and I just updated the JS so the console.log is displaying the old position and the new position, which are the same. http://codepen.io/IronHKristy/pen/BpzRLP   Oh, also, the only obstacle on that grid so far is at position [0, 2] so in order to test it, just type "rffff" in the input box.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a `newPosition` variable that calculates the new location. Then check if this new position has an obstacle before updating the rover's position.

Alternatively, you can add a `prevPosition` to `myRover` to store the previous position.

Comment: @KH2017 Please edit your question to show what you have tried. Also be sure to show the outcome and explain how it differs from what you want.